# Windows Wallpaper directory (custom)

Tags: windows, windows-7, wallpaper

Often I download a photo that I like, then set the photo as my background. Then I delete the photo (and the wallpaper stays there).

Where is the copy of the file (such that its still able to display the file).

I mistakenly changed my background and now I can't find the photo I was using before.

On windows 7

Thanks

Comment: Do you really first download the file? Or do you right click it within your browser and set it as Wallpaper from there? If so what browser do you use?

Comment: chrome, but im fairly sure I downloaded it. what would that directory be out of interest though

Comment: Sad, I think  only Firefox and InternetExplorer have that feature where you can set it directly from within the browser, for chrome you would need an extension which you probably don't have if you are sure you downloaded it anyway. I assume you checked chromes default download folder already?

Comment: I did some tests on my pc with these results: The current wallpaper is in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\TranscodedWallpaper.jpg (as posted  below) however any older ones are deleted in windows 7. In Windows XP they were stored as well with 1-x. So your only bet if you changed the background and deleted the file is the so called Shadow Copies. If you got that feature activated go to that folder and follow the instructions here: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/previous-versions-files-faq#1TC=windows-7 . You may be able to retrieve it form an earlier date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the actual path in the registry key named Wallpaper at [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop]

Usually it's something like:

C:\Documents and Settings\ [YOURUSERNAME] \Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\Wallpaper1.bmp

Windows 7 (Reference):

C:\Windows\Web\Wallpaper (default themes)

C:\Users\ [YOURUSERNAME] \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Themes ( any new themes that you might have installed )

C:\Users\ [YOURUSERNAME] \AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes ( any other pictures that you might have made as an wallpaper.

right-click on the desktop and pick Personalize
click Desktop Background
right-click on the selected image and either:
pick Properties and look under General, Location
or, pick something under Open With

Comment: Thanks, the bottom 3 links dont have them and I dont have access to documents and settings (work pc), but ill see if I can find it

Comment: managed to bypass the security and its not there. searched all the jpg's on my pc and no good :(